# Яка різниця між мерзенно і мерзотно?

Tags: вживання-слів

Яка різниця між мерзенно і мерзотно?

Comment: схоже, що це синоніми

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова "мерзенно" та "мерзотно" мають подібне значення, але вживаються в дещо різних контекстах. Обидва ці прикметники відносяться до чогось вкрай неприємного, відразливого або огидного. Однак, зазвичай, "мерзенно" використовується для опису почуттів або вражень (наприклад, відчувати себе мерзенно), тоді як "мерзотно" частіше стосується опису об'єктів або дій (наприклад, мерзотна поведінка). Це розмежування не є абсолютним і може варіюватися залежно від контексту та особистих переваг користувача мови.